# Como hacer para mostrar el resultado correcto en Wordle

Tags: javascript, html

Soy un principiante en HTML y JavaScript y estoy tratando de hacer un Wordle pero no me sale la respuesta correcta cuando termino la cantidad de intentos y no acierto. Tampoco salta la palabra si acierto la correcta.

He usado el siguiente código para mostrar el resultado:

```
function revelarPalabraCorrecta() { 
    const contenedor = document.getElementById('guesses'); 
    contenedor.innerHTML += `<p>La palabra correcta era: ${palabra}</p>`; 
}
```

Esperaba que saliera la palabra correcta.
Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Buenas, Andrés, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Donde está definida la palabra? ¿Y porqué piensas que se va a sustituir en la cadena de caracteres si pones ${palabra}?